# Открытие файлов

Tags: c#

Вот скажите, у меня есть Конструктор игр Eclipse, в нем есть редактор вещей, и можно сохранить этот предмет .item, а вот я например хочу сделать свой редактор на C#.NET, но вот как считывать все это?

[image: снимок]

Мне не нужен код, мне надо просто понять, как, например, считать в этом файле, сколько здоровья, сколько силы? Как программа будет распознавать, что вот эту строчку надо поместить в первый TextBox, а вот эти эти строки в эти TextBox'в.

Answer (score 4):

В два этапа.

Сначала нужно прочитать файл и преобразовать его в объектную модель его содержимого. Для каждого поля ввода создайте в этой модели свойство.

А потом прочитанный объект уже привязывайте к элементам управления пользовательского интерфейса.

Если формат файла не предопределён, используйте для чтения и сохранения данных сериализаторы, чтобы не реализовывать это вручную.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно сказал **Modus**, что нужно использовать сериализацию.

[Простенький пример использования сериализации](http://code-inside.net/serialization/)